# Варианты фильтрации в @tanstack/react-table

Tags: reactjs

Я использую `@tanstack/react-table` для создания таблицы для моего веб-приложения. В моей таблице есть фильтры по двум полям: `name` и `email`. Если я введу "name1" в поле `name` и "email1" в поле `email`, таблица покажет мне строки, где `name` - "name1" И `email` - "email1". Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы в таблице отображались строки, где `name` - "name1" ИЛИ `email` - "email1"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]